# Podman isn't working in Remote Containers in Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, podman

Any hints on why [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) isn't working with `podman` on **Windows**?

- Installed `podman` `v4.2.0` on **Windows 11** via [.msi package](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/tag/v4.2.0)
- Set `remote.containers.dockerPath` to `podman` in **VS Code** Settings
- Run `podman machine init`
- Run `podman machine start`
- Open `Remote Explorer` in **VS Code** and be presented with the following:

  [image: Remote Explorer in VS Code]

Everything is working with `podman` — `pull`, `run`, `images`, etc, but [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) on VSCode doesn't recognize `podman`.

After running `Remote-Containers Developer: Show All Logs...` in VS Code:

```
[2022-08-21T12:55:15.916Z] Start: Run: podman version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[2022-08-21T12:55:16.080Z] Stop (164 ms): Run: podman version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[2022-08-21T12:55:16.080Z] Cannot connect to Podman. Please verify your connection to the Linux system using `podman system connection list`, or try `podman machine init` and `podman machine start` to manage a new Linux VM
Error: unable to connect to Podman. failed to create sshClient: dial unix \\.\pipe\openssh-ssh-agent: connect: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

And `podman system connection list` in a terminal:

```
Name                         URI                                                          Identity                                      Default
podman-machine-default       ssh://user@localhost:62078/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock  C:\Users\Edmundo\.ssh\podman-machine-default  true
podman-machine-default-root  ssh://root@localhost:62078/run/podman/podman.sock            C:\Users\Edmundo\.ssh\podman-machine-default  false
```

Related Issues: [#6957](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6957), [#6747](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6747).

Comment: The error messages would be easier to read if they would be written as text in the question (in addition to the PNG format of the screenshot).

Comment: I gave up using the windows installation (`.msi`) and installed podman inside ubuntu wsl. It works this way.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm you are running the latest build (prerelease)

v0.236.1.

(there are known issues on github with earlier release, fixed in this version)

Comment: Thank you. But, same error message in v0.236.1

Comment: I think this error is with the extension since the Docker extension (`ms-azuretools.vscode-docker`) is working fine with Docker Path set to `podman`. Guess I'm just gonna wait for a patch...

Comment: fwiw, I wrote a patch for vscode-docker to get podman working. plz see:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/pull/3531

Comment: also - having recently reviewed the code (today), it's highly unlikely *nearly impossible* that the vscode-docker plugin is working with podman.  is docker also installed? .. I say this because as the pull request indicates, the path to the docker socket is hardcoded in the source.

Comment: Docker is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

in a WSL shell, i.e. for debugging try this

first - try to start podman podlib REST api (for socket, lifetime 5000 sec. - set to zero for "forever")

```
podman system service -t 5000 &
```

then symlink the podman.sock to the location vscode expects:

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/wslg/runtime-dir/podman/podman.sock /var/run/docker.sock
```

if none of that works, would you mind posting a dump:

```
podman info
```

HINT: check the `podman info` YAML output for `host | remoteSocket | path` & make sure it matches the path /mnt/wslg/runtime-dir/podman/podman.sock above.

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/run/docker.sock': File exists`



Currently is `/var/run/docker.sock -> /run/podman/podman.sock`

Comment: `podman info --format '{{.Host.RemoteSocket.Path}}'`

`/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock`

Comment: so there is an issue, the paths don't match. 
the /var/run/docker.sock is hardcoded into the plugin as a vscode as a const, but it's not pointing to the same location as your podman podlib path.  I won't speculate how this happened but re-link the socket and you should be fine:

`sudo ln -sf /run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-system-service.1.html
suggests that both paths are valid, the divergence in paths is rootful vs rootless configurations of podman

Comment: if it still doesn't work, the next step `podman info --format '{{.Host.Security.Rootless}}'`

Comment: Didn't work. Tried both rootless and rootfull with `podman machine set --rootful`.

Answer (score 0):

The bug being tracked on [GitHub](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/15338). One step you should also do is enable `Run in WSL` in VS Code Development Container extension settings. Then it will run the podman commands in the `podman-machine-default` wsl instance.